# Gradle build file working fine for version 2.10 but after upgrading to 4.6 its stopped working

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, war

Copying resources to WEB-INF from `makeWarTask`. Its working fine for **Gradle** version `2.10`. But after upgrading to `4.6` its stopped copying same.

```
task makeWarTask(type: War) {
  webInf{
      from('build/resources/slave') {
          include 'base.xml'
          into('classes/')
      }
      from('build/classes/slave/com/test/util') {
          include 'DBConstant.class'
          into('classes/com/test/util/')
      }
    }
}
```

Is there any version syntax update or anything else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Gradle 4.0, the compiled classes are not anymore in `build/classes/<source-set-name>`, but in `build/classes/<language>/<source-set-name>`, see the [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/release-notes.html#location-of-classes-in-the-build-directory). So in your case probably in `build/classes/java/slave`.

Your task configuration should look like this:

```
task makeWarTask(type: War) {
  webInf{
      from('build/resources/slave') {
          include 'base.xml'
          into('classes/')
      }
      from('build/classes/java/slave/com/test/util') {
          include 'DBConstant.class'
          into('classes/com/test/util/')
      }
  }
}
```